# How does this "print a heart" program work in C?

Tags: c++, c, logic, ascii

I stumbled across this code on some blog over the internet. It's a pretty interesting program, but I've been trying to figure out how the program actually works for a while and I've been stuck at it since then. I just don't get how the program prints the symmetry. Is one half of the heart printed and the other half replicated by mirroring it?  If anyone can help me figure out the logic, I'd appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

```
//Include Headers.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int x, y, size=20;
    for (x=0; x<size; x++)
    {
        for (y=0; y<=4*size; y++)
        {
            double dist1 = sqrt( pow(x-size,2) + pow(y-size,2) );
            double dist2 = sqrt( pow(x-size,2) + pow(y-3*size,2) );
            if (dist1 < size + 0.5 || dist2 < size + 0.5 )
                 printf("%c",97);
            else
                 printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (x = 1; x <= 2*size; x++)
    {
        for (y=0; y<x; y++)
        printf(" ");
        for (y=0; y<4*size + 1 - 2*x; y++)
            printf("%c",86);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: A fairly simple answer to your question sits right there in your code. Rather than print asterisks, print the `dist1` and `dist2` values, one pair per line.

Comment: Any pictorial explanation would be helpful.

Comment: For someone so profoundly interested in working this out, you don't appear to have looked at the code or run it thru a debugger. The answer to your question about symmetry is in the fact that `printf("\n");` is inside the x loop...

Comment: http://ideone.com/YYQ075 -- It looks more like two parabolas or semi-circles and a triangle to me, only vaguely resembling a heart.  Definitely not something I'd write on a note to my wife if I was leaving her a reminder to feed the cat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't doing much to take advantage of symmetry.

Presumably the part you care about is the upper half of the heart, since the lower half is just a basic triangle.

The upper half is computed fairly simply. Although they're normally warped because character cells aren't square, what it's basically doing is just drawing two semi-circles of `size` radius. So, it chooses the center point for each semicircle, then computes the distance from the center to the current point (basic Pythagorean formula). If that distance is less than the chosen radius from the center of either circle, it prints an `a`. Otherwise it prints a space.